# PCMCIA Card SD Reader not recognized

Tags: sd-card, peripherals

I have a Dell 620 running Ubuntu 14.04 (all updates done, fresh install), and an old "Four in One PCMCIA CardReader" plugged into the PCMCDI slot of the Dell machine.
I have a working SD Card in the card reader, but this machine do not see the card.

I tried the SD card directly in another Ubuntu machine (which has a SD Card reader embedded in the hardware), and it works. So the issue is likely to be with the PCMCIA card.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Thanks,
FX